# postgres, If all rows in a column are null, does an index still improve performance?

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm interested in understanding more about the postgres optimiser.

If you have a query for example

```
select * from table where field = value limit 1;
```

but all values of field are null.
Will an index on field still make the query faster as the table grows or does the optimisation phase work out (in some way that doesn't involve passing the entire table) that there are no values that meet the requirement?

I ask because we had a situation where we had an unoptimised simple query (of the form above and where the column wasn't indexed) that went unnoticed even though the table had million of records until one day some real values were injected and suddenly everything died.

Comment: "*or does the optimisation phase work out that there are no values that meet the requirement*" - yes it will work that out, because Postgres (not "psql" - that is the command line client) keeps statistics about the values. But the only way to find that out is to look at the execution plan

Comment: thanks, do you want to add that as an answer and I'll accept it? out of interest, is it possible to list the stats that postgres keeps?

Comment: @mark Yes it is possible: `SELECT * FROM pg_stats  WHERE tablename = ?;` Particularly `most_common_vals` collumn of that view may be interresting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values of `field` are null, the above query will always return no rows, because `field = value` implies `field is not null`. Nulls can only be tested by `is null` or `is not null` operators.

Anyway, indexes (of all types except HASH and GIN) store nulls and hence can improve queries like `filed is null` or `field is not null`. But it really depends on your exact query and distribution of values.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are generally only useful when they are *selective*, i.e. when only a relatively small proportion of rows match the index. So generally an index on a column that's all one value (null, or otherwise) will not get used because a sequential scan will be faster.

The other time an index can be useful is when part of the query can be satisfied entirely from the index via an index-only scan. It's not likely that you'll be able to do that with a column that's all nulls, but you might choose to incorporate the column into a composite index if that enables index-only scan use for a heavily used query.